# Inserting <script>codehere</script> in header via JS in the body?

Tags: javascript, php, html

http://jsfiddle.net/8wGRg/

`<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild("<scr" + "ipt>alert('Hi!');</scr" + "ipt>");
</script>`

I have a PHP string which contains JS code. For the sake of this code, lets say my string is `<script>alert('Hi!');</script>`. Within the body of my HTML document, how can I use JS to insert the JS string into the head.

As you can see, I'm breaking the word script into two parts so that it doesn't actually process it in the body before pushing it to the head.

The PHP string contains this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/1019006/ba_ad_footer_728x90', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1378123123651-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

PHP code to generate JS:

```
<?php $header_code = $GLOBALS['settings']['header_code']; // just an example of how I load the code ?>
```

JS to insert the PHP

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild("<?php echo $header_code; ?>");
```

Comment: Where exactly is your *"php string"* in relation to your javascript?

Comment: That's not exactly what i meant. I mean, how is that getting to javascript, for you to append with javascript. I'm trying to figure out why you want to append it with javascript in the first place rather than just having php include it.

Comment: Because it's called via a shortcode which loads after the header is already loaded. Code updated too.

Comment: hmm... i'm no wordpress developer, but i can't help but think there must be a way within wordpress to insert that string directly into the header without having to deal with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't append it because you are trying to append a string instead of a DOM node.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('alert("Hi!")'));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: The string contains the <script></script> tags though, so I don't need to create them. I may have to find a way around this though.

Comment: @Branndon what's stopping you from striping the `<script>` tags off?

Comment: Then take the script tags out. Use `.replace()` if need be.

Comment: again my answer 3 minutes later... downvoted as well.